# THREE.js generate UV coordinate

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, texture-mapping, uv-mapping

I am working on importing a model into a scene using the THREE.js OBJ loader.

I know that I am able to import the geometry fine, because when I assign a MeshNormalMaterial to it, it shows up great. However, if I use anything that requires UV coordinates, It gives me the error:

```
[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1
```

I know this is because the loaded OBJ has no UV coordinates, but I was wondering if there was any way to generate the needed texture coordinates. I have tried

```
material.needsUpdate = true;
geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
```

...but to no avail.

Is there any way to automagically generate UV textures using three.js, or do I have to assign the coordinates myself?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no automatic way to calculate UV.

You must calculate yourself. Calculate a UV for a plane is quite easy, this site explains how: [calculating texture coordinates](http://paulyg.f2s.com/uv.htm)

For a complex shape, I don't know how. Maybe you could detect planar surface.

**EDIT**

Here is a sample code for a planar surface `(x, y, z)` where `z = 0`:

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox();

var max = geometry.boundingBox.max,
    min = geometry.boundingBox.min;
var offset = new THREE.Vector2(0 - min.x, 0 - min.y);
var range = new THREE.Vector2(max.x - min.x, max.y - min.y);
var faces = geometry.faces;

geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

for (var i = 0; i < faces.length ; i++) {

    var v1 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].a], 
        v2 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].b], 
        v3 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].c];

    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
        new THREE.Vector2((v1.x + offset.x)/range.x ,(v1.y + offset.y)/range.y),
        new THREE.Vector2((v2.x + offset.x)/range.x ,(v2.y + offset.y)/range.y),
        new THREE.Vector2((v3.x + offset.x)/range.x ,(v3.y + offset.y)/range.y)
    ]);
}
geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Comment: To help those that might look for an inexistent solution... for a "complex", irregular shape the only (sane) way is to use a 3D software like Blender, manually place the texture on the model and export a file.

Comment: Unfortunately this syntax doesn't work since three.js r.125. Does anyone know how to convert it to the current version of three.js ?

Answer (score 19):

The other answers here were a great help but didn't quite fit my requirements to apply a repeating pattern texture to all sides of a shape with mostly flat surfaces. The problem is that using only the x and y components as u and v results in weird stretched textures on vertical surfaces.

My solution below uses surface normals to pick which two components (x, y and z) to map to u and v. It's still pretty crude but it works quite well.

```
function assignUVs(geometry) {

    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

    geometry.faces.forEach(function(face) {

        var components = ['x', 'y', 'z'].sort(function(a, b) {
            return Math.abs(face.normal[a]) > Math.abs(face.normal[b]);
        });

        var v1 = geometry.vertices[face.a];
        var v2 = geometry.vertices[face.b];
        var v3 = geometry.vertices[face.c];

        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
            new THREE.Vector2(v1[components[0]], v1[components[1]]),
            new THREE.Vector2(v2[components[0]], v2[components[1]]),
            new THREE.Vector2(v3[components[0]], v3[components[1]])
        ]);

    });

    geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

This function doesn't normalise the UVs to the size of the object. This works better when applying the same texture to different sized objects in the same scene. However depending on the size of your world coordinate system, you'll probably need to scale and repeat the texture as well:

```
texture.repeat.set(0.1, 0.1);
texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this! Would have taken me ages to get this right.

Comment: Thanks for saving me lots of time!

Answer (score 9):

Box UV mapping is possibly most useful thing in three.js configurators of any sort, -
https://jsfiddle.net/mmalex/pcjbysn1/

The solution works per face both with indexed and non-indexed buffer geometries.

[image: three.js UV mapping box]

Example of usage:

```
//build some mesh
var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.DodecahedronGeometry(2.5, 0));
let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0x10f0f0,
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('http://mbnsay.com/rayys/images/1K_UV_checker.jpg')
});

//find out the dimensions, to let texture size 100% fit without stretching
bufferGeometry.computeBoundingBox();
let bboxSize = bufferGeometry.boundingBox.getSize();
let uvMapSize = Math.min(bboxSize.x, bboxSize.y, bboxSize.z);

//calculate UV coordinates, if uv attribute is not present, it will be added
applyBoxUV(bufferGeometry, new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(cube.matrix), uvMapSize);

//let three.js know
bufferGeometry.attributes.uv.needsUpdate = true;
```

The example is based on the following implementation of `applyBoxUV`

```js
function _applyBoxUV(geom, transformMatrix, bbox, bbox_max_size) {

    let coords = [];
    coords.length = 2 * geom.attributes.position.array.length / 3;

    // geom.removeAttribute('uv');
    if (geom.attributes.uv === undefined) {
        geom.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(coords, 2));
    }

    //maps 3 verts of 1 face on the better side of the cube
    //side of the cube can be XY, XZ or YZ
    let makeUVs = function(v0, v1, v2) {

        //pre-rotate the model so that cube sides match world axis
        v0.applyMatrix4(transformMatrix);
        v1.applyMatrix4(transformMatrix);
        v2.applyMatrix4(transformMatrix);

        //get normal of the face, to know into which cube side it maps better
        let n = new THREE.Vector3();
        n.crossVectors(v1.clone().sub(v0), v1.clone().sub(v2)).normalize();

        n.x = Math.abs(n.x);
        n.y = Math.abs(n.y);
        n.z = Math.abs(n.z);

        let uv0 = new THREE.Vector2();
        let uv1 = new THREE.Vector2();
        let uv2 = new THREE.Vector2();
        // xz mapping
        if (n.y > n.x && n.y > n.z) {
            uv0.x = (v0.x - bbox.min.x) / bbox_max_size;
            uv0.y = (bbox.max.z - v0.z) / bbox_max_size;

            uv1.x = (v1.x - bbox.min.x) / bbox_max_size;
            uv1.y = (bbox.max.z - v1.z) / bbox_max_size;

            uv2.x = (v2.x - bbox.min.x) / bbox_max_size;
            uv2.y = (bbox.max.z - v2.z) / bbox_max_size;
        } else
        if (n.x > n.y && n.x > n.z) {
            uv0.x = (v0.z - bbox.min.z) / bbox_max_size;
            uv0.y = (v0.y - bbox.min.y) / bbox_max_size;

            uv1.x = (v1.z - bbox.min.z) / bbox_max_size;
            uv1.y = (v1.y - bbox.min.y) / bbox_max_size;

            uv2.x = (v2.z - bbox.min.z) / bbox_max_size;
            uv2.y = (v2.y - bbox.min.y) / bbox_max_size;
        } else
        if (n.z > n.y && n.z > n.x) {
            uv0.x = (v0.x - bbox.min.x) / bbox_max_size;
            uv0.y = (v0.y - bbox.min.y) / bbox_max_size;

            uv1.x = (v1.x - bbox.min.x) / bbox_max_size;
            uv1.y = (v1.y - bbox.min.y) / bbox_max_size;

            uv2.x = (v2.x - bbox.min.x) / bbox_max_size;
            uv2.y = (v2.y - bbox.min.y) / bbox_max_size;
        }

        return {
            uv0: uv0,
            uv1: uv1,
            uv2: uv2
        };
    };

    if (geom.index) { // is it indexed buffer geometry?
        for (let vi = 0; vi < geom.index.array.length; vi += 3) {
            let idx0 = geom.index.array[vi];
            let idx1 = geom.index.array[vi + 1];
            let idx2 = geom.index.array[vi + 2];

            let vx0 = geom.attributes.position.array[3 * idx0];
            let vy0 = geom.attributes.position.array[3 * idx0 + 1];
            let vz0 = geom.attributes.position.array[3 * idx0 + 2];

            let vx1 = geom.attributes.position.array[3 * idx1];
            let vy1 = geom.attributes.position.array[3 * idx1 + 1];
            let vz1 = geom.attributes.position.array[3 * idx1 + 2];

            let vx2 = geom.attributes.position.array[3 * idx2];
            let vy2 = geom.attributes.position.array[3 * idx2 + 1];
            let vz2 = geom.attributes.position.array[3 * idx2 + 2];

            let v0 = new THREE.Vector3(vx0, vy0, vz0);
            let v1 = new THREE.Vector3(vx1, vy1, vz1);
            let v2 = new THREE.Vector3(vx2, vy2, vz2);

            let uvs = makeUVs(v0, v1, v2, coords);

            coords[2 * idx0] = uvs.uv0.x;
            coords[2 * idx0 + 1] = uvs.uv0.y;

            coords[2 * idx1] = uvs.uv1.x;
            coords[2 * idx1 + 1] = uvs.uv1.y;

            coords[2 * idx2] = uvs.uv2.x;
            coords[2 * idx2 + 1] = uvs.uv2.y;
        }
    } else {
        for (let vi = 0; vi < geom.attributes.position.array.length; vi += 9) {
            let vx0 = geom.attributes.position.array[vi];
            let vy0 = geom.attributes.position.array[vi + 1];
            let vz0 = geom.attributes.position.array[vi + 2];

            let vx1 = geom.attributes.position.array[vi + 3];
            let vy1 = geom.attributes.position.array[vi + 4];
            let vz1 = geom.attributes.position.array[vi + 5];

            let vx2 = geom.attributes.position.array[vi + 6];
            let vy2 = geom.attributes.position.array[vi + 7];
            let vz2 = geom.attributes.position.array[vi + 8];

            let v0 = new THREE.Vector3(vx0, vy0, vz0);
            let v1 = new THREE.Vector3(vx1, vy1, vz1);
            let v2 = new THREE.Vector3(vx2, vy2, vz2);

            let uvs = makeUVs(v0, v1, v2, coords);

            let idx0 = vi / 3;
            let idx1 = idx0 + 1;
            let idx2 = idx0 + 2;

            coords[2 * idx0] = uvs.uv0.x;
            coords[2 * idx0 + 1] = uvs.uv0.y;

            coords[2 * idx1] = uvs.uv1.x;
            coords[2 * idx1 + 1] = uvs.uv1.y;

            coords[2 * idx2] = uvs.uv2.x;
            coords[2 * idx2 + 1] = uvs.uv2.y;
        }
    }

    geom.attributes.uv.array = new Float32Array(coords);
}

function applyBoxUV(bufferGeometry, transformMatrix, boxSize) {

    if (transformMatrix === undefined) {
        transformMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
    }

    if (boxSize === undefined) {
        let geom = bufferGeometry;
        geom.computeBoundingBox();
        let bbox = geom.boundingBox;

        let bbox_size_x = bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x;
        let bbox_size_z = bbox.max.z - bbox.min.z;
        let bbox_size_y = bbox.max.y - bbox.min.y;

        boxSize = Math.max(bbox_size_x, bbox_size_y, bbox_size_z);
    }

    let uvBbox = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(-boxSize / 2, -boxSize / 2, -boxSize / 2), new THREE.Vector3(boxSize / 2, boxSize / 2, boxSize / 2));

    _applyBoxUV(bufferGeometry, transformMatrix, uvBbox, boxSize);

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The answers here are brilliant and helped me a lot. 
Only one thing: If you are updating vertices, do not re-assign uvs, but set them, as in (scope is my geometry):

```
scope.updateUVs = (copy=true) => {

    scope.computeBoundingBox();

    var max     = scope.boundingBox.max;
    var min     = scope.boundingBox.min;

    var offset  = new THREE.Vector2(0 - min.x, 0 - min.y);
    var range   = new THREE.Vector2(max.x - min.x, max.y - min.y);

    if (!copy) {
        scope.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];
    }
    var faces = scope.faces;

    for (i = 0; i < scope.faces.length ; i++) {

      var v1 = scope.vertices[faces[i].a];
      var v2 = scope.vertices[faces[i].b];
      var v3 = scope.vertices[faces[i].c];

      var uv0 = new THREE.Vector2( ( v1.x + offset.x ) / range.x , ( v1.y + offset.y ) / range.y );
      var uv1 = new THREE.Vector2( ( v2.x + offset.x ) / range.x , ( v2.y + offset.y ) / range.y );
      var uv2 = new THREE.Vector2( ( v3.x + offset.x ) / range.x , ( v3.y + offset.y ) / range.y );

      if (copy) {
          var uvs =scope.faceVertexUvs[0][i];
          uvs[0].copy(uv0);
          uvs[1].copy(uv1);
          uvs[2].copy(uv2);
      } else {
          scope.faceVertexUvs[0].push([uv0, uv1, uv2]);
      }
    }

    scope.uvsNeedUpdate = true;

}
```

Comment: You forgot to declare `i`

Answer (score 3):

This is a general version that works for spherical mapping (yaw, pitch coordinates), see example [here](https://www.clicktorelease.com/code/spherical-normal-mapping/), (look at *loadSuzanne* function):

```
function assignUVs(geometry) {

    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

    geometry.faces.forEach(function(face) {

        var uvs = [];
        var ids = [ 'a', 'b', 'c'];
        for( var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++ ) {
            var vertex = geometry.vertices[ face[ ids[ i ] ] ].clone();

            var n = vertex.normalize();
            var yaw = .5 - Math.atan( n.z, - n.x ) / ( 2.0 * Math.PI );
            var pitch = .5 - Math.asin( n.y ) / Math.PI;

            var u = yaw,
                v = pitch;
            uvs.push( new THREE.Vector2( u, v ) );
        }
        geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ].push( uvs );
    });

    geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

Comment: I tried the above solution for a sphere geometry. Although it did produce some result, it wasn't working correctly. So I fixed it - you can see it in action here: http://codepen.io/knee-cola/pen/XMVBwQ

Comment: atan expects one parameter, you should use atan2 to have the correct outcome.