# ThreeJS pass uv coordinates to RawShaderMaterial?

Tags: three.js, shader, uv-mapping

I'm trying to create a shader with a texture map on it from scratch. Looking at the other materials (shaders) and their sources, it seems like they all have a "uv" attribute passed to them. I'm having a hard time figuring out where that uv attribute is generated and assigned. Is it set on the geometry, the material, or both?

I'm using default THREE.Geometry objects, like `THREE.SphereGeometry`. I assumed those would already have attributes set on them, but when I inspect their meshes as scene children I don't see any attribute key/value set on them.

This is an example of the shader generated by a `ShaderMaterial` or other:

Vertex shader

```
attribute vec2 uv;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main()  {
    vUv = uv;
```

Fragment shader

```
varying vec2 vUv;
uniform sampler2D map;

void main()  {
    vec4 texel = texture2D( map, vUv );
```

However, when I attempt the above, my shader (with RawShaderMaterial) just goes blank and I get a "could not compile."

Is there some magic in THREE that sets up a relationship between shader, object and attributes?

I found a [THREE.js generate UV coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774648/three-js-generate-uv-coordinate) question, but again, I'm guessing a THREE default object already has UV attributes set correctly?

I specifically want to use a RawShaderMaterial in this case. Can someone point me to the place in the THREE source where UVs are generated for objects / passed to shaders, or tell me how to properly set up UVs to use in the fragment / vertex at runtime?

Comment: It only says "could not compile"? Could you upload the test somewhere?

Comment: I made this http://jsfiddle.net/4wkFu/125/ which actually works, so I think I'm just doing something wrong in my setup.