# Texture rendering problems

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Hej there,

i have a problem with the rendering of a texture on an OBJ imported model.

In this image you can see, how the texture is rendered.

[image: wrong texture]

and here you can see how the texture should look (mapped to the object)

[image: current texture]

And here is my code:

```
      loader = new THREE.ImageLoader();
      loader.load('./tex/Stuhl1-vorn.jpg', function (image) {
          var imageObj = new Image();
          imageObj.src = $(image).prop('src');

          var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          canvas.width = imageObj.width;
          canvas.height = imageObj.height;

          var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.width, imageObj.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

          texture.image = canvas;
          texture.needsUpdate = true;
      });

      var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
          map: texture,
          needsUpdate: true
      });

      var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
      loader.load('obj/sitz.obj', function (object) {
          object.traverse(function (child) {
              if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                  child.material = material;
                  child.side = THREE.FrontSide;
              }
          });

          object.position.y = -400;
          scene.add(object);

      }, onProgress, onError);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your imported model does not have uvw coordinates.
Load the model into a 3d modelling program, add uvw coordinates, export with uvw coordinates.

Or if you want to do it in code, maybe this question/answer will help: [THREE.js generate UV coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774648/three-js-generate-uv-coordinate)