# How to apply a texture to a custom geometry in Three.js

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I successfully applied a texture to a cube geometry with this:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(10, 10, 10);
var meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ transparent: false, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/app/images/wood.jpg') });
meshMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, meshMaterial);
```

With this I get a nice textured cube like this:

[image]

Now I want to apply the same texture (512x512 jpg image) to a custom model I'm loading from an STL and this is what I get (in this case a pyramid):

[image]

This is the code:

```
loader.load(jsonParam.url, function (geometry) {
            var meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ transparent: false, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/app/images/wood.jpg') });
            meshMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, meshMaterial);

            mesh.castShadow = false;
            mesh.receiveShadow = true;
            scene.add(mesh);
        });
```

Why the texture is not being applied and I get only what seems to be an average of the texture colors?

Comment: Does your model have UV coordinates?

Comment: @2pha No, it's an STL model, do I need UV mapping?

Comment: yes. without UV mapping, the shader does not know which part of the image to put where on the model.

Comment: @2pha How do I load an UV map in Three.js?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need UV mapping.
You can either edit the model in modelling software to add UV coordinates or maybe generate them as in the answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774648/three-js-generate-uv-coordinate).
I suppose another option would be to create your own shader that maps the texture to the model surface without using UV coordinates.

Comment: Is there any way to produce the UV Map programmatically as in the link above but for non-planar surfaces? I  don't care if the texture get's a little distorded

Comment: You would have to apply some other type of [projection method](http://softimage.wiki.softimage.com/xsidocs/tex_basicproc_TypesofTextureProjection.htm) but that could probably not be used as a generic method for all the models you have. This is why so many UV mapping software packages are available.