# Programmatically generate simple UV Mapping for models

Tags: three.js, uv-mapping

Coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932860/how-to-apply-a-texture-to-a-custom-geometry-in-three-js#34937000%20%22%22) question I'm trying to generate UV Mappings programmatically with Three.js for some models, I need this because my models are being generated programmatically too and I need to apply a simple texture to them. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774648/three-js-generate-uv-coordinate) and successfully generated UV mapping for some simple 3D text but when applying the same mapping to more complex models it just doesn't work.

The texture I'm trying to apply is something like this:

[image]

The black background it's just transparent in the PNG image. I need to apply this to my models, it's just a glitter effect so I don't care about the exact position in the model, is any way to create a simple UV Map programatically for this cases?

I'm using this code from the linked question which works great for planar models but doesn't work for non-planar models:

```
assignUVs = function( geometry ){

    geometry.computeBoundingBox();

    var max     = geometry.boundingBox.max;
    var min     = geometry.boundingBox.min;

    var offset  = new THREE.Vector2(0 - min.x, 0 - min.y);
    var range   = new THREE.Vector2(max.x - min.x, max.y - min.y);

    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];
    var faces = geometry.faces;

    for (i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length ; i++) {

      var v1 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].a];
      var v2 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].b];
      var v3 = geometry.vertices[faces[i].c];

      geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
        new THREE.Vector2( ( v1.x + offset.x ) / range.x , ( v1.y + offset.y ) / range.y ),
        new THREE.Vector2( ( v2.x + offset.x ) / range.x , ( v2.y + offset.y ) / range.y ),
        new THREE.Vector2( ( v3.x + offset.x ) / range.x , ( v3.y + offset.y ) / range.y )
      ]);

    }

    geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

Comment: If it's just a glitter effect, would it be better just to create a shader? something like [THIS](http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/voronoi_point_lights.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to be more specific. Here, I'll apply UV mapping programmatically

```
for (i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length ; i++) {
   geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
     new THREE.Vector2( 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector2( 0, 0 ),
     new THREE.Vector2( 0, 0 ),
   ]);
}
```

Happy?

There are an infinite ways of applying UV coordinates. How about this

```
for (i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length ; i++) {
   geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
     new THREE.Vector2( Math.random(), Math.random() ),
     new THREE.Vector2( Math.random(), Math.random() ),
     new THREE.Vector2( Math.random(), Math.random() ),
   ]);
}
```

There's no *RIGHT* answer. There's just whatever you want to do is up to you. It's kind of like asking how do I apply pencil to paper.

Sorry to be so snarky, just pointing out the question is in one sense nonsensical.

Anyway, there are a few common methods for applying a texture.

- Spherical mapping

  Imagine your model is translucent, there's a sphere inside made of film and inside the sphere is a point light so that it projects (like a movie projector) from the sphere in all directions. So you do the math to computer the correct UVs for that situation

  To get a point on there sphere multiply your points by the inverse of the world matrix for the sphere then normalize the result. After that though there's still the problem of how the texture itself is mapped to the imaginary sphere for which again there are an infinite number of ways.

  The simplest way is I guess called [mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) which is how most 2d maps of the world work. they have the problem that lots of space is wasted at the north and south poles. Assuming x,y,z are the normalized coordinates mentioned in the previous paragraph then

  ```
  U = Math.atan2(z, x) / Math.PI * 0.5 - 0.5;
  V = 0.5 - Math.asin(y) / Math.PI;
  ```
- Projection Mapping

  This is just like a movie. You have a 2d image being projected from a point. Imagine you pointed a movie projector (or a projection TV) at a chair. Compute those points

  Computing these points is exactly like computing the 2D image from 3D data that nearly all WebGL apps do. Usually they have a line in their vertex shader like this

  ```
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
  ```

  Where `matrix = worldViewProjection`. You can then do

  ```
  clipSpace = gl_Position.xy / gl_Position.w
  ```

  You now have x,y values that go from -1 to +1. You then convert them
  to 0 to 1 for UV coords

  ```
  uv = clipSpace * 0.5 + 0.5;
  ```

  Of course normally you'd compute UV coordinates at init time in JavaScript but the concept is the same.
- Planar Mapping

  This is the almost the same as projection mapping except imagine the projector, instead of being a point, is the same size as you want to project it. In other words, with projection mapping as you move your model closer to the projector the picture being projected will get smaller but with planar it won't.

  Following the projection mapping example the only difference here is using an orthographic projection instead of a perspective projection.
- Cube Mapping?

  This is effectively planar mapping from 6 directions. It's up to you
  to decide which UV coordinates get which of the 6 planes. I'd guess
  most of the time you'd take the normal of the triangle to see which
  plane it most faces, then do planar mapping from that plane.

  Actually I might be getting my terms mixed up. You can also do 
  real cube mapping where you have a cube texture but that requires
  U,V,W instead of just U,V. For that it's the same as the sphere
  example except you just use the normalized coordinates directly as
  U,V,W.
- Cylindrical mapping

  This is like sphere mapping except assume there's tiny cylinder projecting on to your model. Unlike a sphere a cylinder has orientation but basically you can move the points of the model into the orientation of the cylinder then assuming x,y,z are now relative to the cylinder (in other words you multiplied them by the inverse matrix of the matrix that represents the orientation of the cylinder), then .

  ```
  U = Math.atan2(x, z) / Math.PI * 0.5 + 0.5
  V = y
  ```

2 more solutions

1. Maybe you want Environment Mapping?

   [Here's 1 example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_balls_reflection.html) and [Here's another](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_envmaps.html).
2. Maybe you should consider using a modeling package like Maya or Blender that have [UV editors](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/UV_Map_Basics) and UV projectors built in.