# ThreeJS/GLSL Projection Mapping a Gradient

Tags: opengl-es, three.js, glsl, webgl

I'm trying to apply a gradient texture to a model using a gradient texture derived from CSS. The idea is that a user could adjust the stops/colors of a gradient and then apply the gradient to a model to match the current camera view as it's rotated around. I've had a very hard time understanding how to implement something like [this tutorial](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/06/how-to-project-decals/).

I've created a very simple example with a hard coded gradient image and Suzanne the monkey, which you can find here:

https://github.com/abogartz/projection-mapping

(To run this, you can use the provided Browser-Sync setup or just run a simple server on index.html)

Right now, the Suzanne model applies the texture as per its own UVs. This results in a gradient that is not linear across the face:

[image]

What I would like is to use "projection mapping" instead, where the gradient starts from the leftmost vertex and ends at the rightmost, no matter how the camera is rotated (I'll save the camera matrix on a user action and use that as a uniform later).

The result should be more like this (of course with lighting,etc)

[image]

My current shader looks like this:

```
<script id='fragmentShader' type='x-shader/x-fragment'>
uniform vec2 u_mouse;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_time;
uniform sampler2D u_gradient_tex;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_gradient_tex,vUv);
}
```

Obviously, the vUv varying is not what I want, so how do I calculate the projection coordinate instead?

Comment: So the gradient needs to be the same no matter what angle the model is facing?

Comment: Well, yeah. I want the camera rotation to control the gradient, but for now it could be from any known angle, such as from the front.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, I created this for you so you can see the rough idea on how you would implement this:

http://glslsandbox.com/e#37464.0

I've done this with a circle but you could do it with a model as well.
Essentially all you need to do is change `gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_gradient_tex,vUv);` to something like `gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_gradient_tex,gl_FragCoord.xy * some_scaling_factor);`

This is changing the texture mapping to be dependant on the FragCoord rather than the model UV.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Ok, I know it's hard to explain, and I apologize if I didn't it phrase it well, but what I need is that the gradient will extend from the left side of the sphere to the right side, no matter where on the screen it is. So for example, if I zoom out, the gradient will still only be rendered at the edges of the sphere.

Comment: @AlexB The only thing you need to do to achieve this is to move the background to where the model is and if you zoom out, then change the some_scaling_factor accordingly (using a uniform probably).

Comment: If you pull down my latest commits, you can see sort of what I'm going for. I'm trying to adjust the position of the gradient through a uniform called "u_gradient_pos". It's close to what I want, but I can't quite get the gradient to move around the model (sort of orbiting like your camera would)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an "easy" way to do what you want. If you want the gradient to always stretch from the left edge of the model to the right edge of the model regardless of orientation then you need to compute the left most and right most vertex position from that perspective / camera angle. Otherwise the gradient would have no anchor (on the left) and no width (how far to stretch to fit)

Typical projection mapping is somewhat described here

[Programatically generate simple UV Mapping for models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958072/programatically-generate-simple-uv-mapping-for-models)

You need the position of the *projector*, then you project from that projector to the points on your mesh to generate UV coordinates. In your case the projector can always be the camera so you can ignore that part. You'd use *planar mapping* but you'd need to compute the left most vertex's position and the right most so you can align the projection so it matches silhouette of your 3D model.

If all you want is a single model with silhouette you can just set the background to your CSS gradient, clear to black then draw with 0,0,0,0 with model to cut a hole.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, 1, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true});
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { 
  color: 0x000000, 
  opacity: 0,
} );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 2;

function resize() {
  var canvas = renderer.domElement;
  var width = canvas.clientWidth;
  var height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds;
  resize();
  
  cube.position.z = Math.sin(time);
  cube.rotation.x = time * 0.817;
  cube.rotation.y = time * 0.923;
  
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
}
requestAnimationFrame( render );
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { 
  width: 100vw; 
  height: 100vh; 
  display: block;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,191,0,1) 23%, rgba(34,255,0,1) 41%, rgba(0,64,255,1) 55%, rgba(170,0,255,1) 75%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.min.js"></script>
```