# Programmatically generating box UVW maps

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d-modelling, uv-mapping, pymeshlab

I'm need to programmatically generate box UVW maps in 3D-models, similar to how `UVW Map -> Box` works in 3ds Max.

[Example with default UV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVulE.png)

[Example with box UV, what I'm after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34oll.png)

I've tried javascript-based solutions [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774648/three-js-generate-uv-coordinate/54438304#54438304) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34958072/programmatically-generate-simple-uv-mapping-for-models), but it seems to give various results depending on if the mesh/geometry is merged or if it already has any built in UV. Or [it has different directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx6Zv.jpg).

Applying box UV-map via Blender or 3ds Max to the same 3D-model always gives perfect results though.

Best case scenario would be a command line tool, similar to how [gltf-pipeline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gltf-pipeline) works:

`generate-box-map -i model.gltf -type box -size 50`

I've found tools/projects such as [PyMeshLab](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [Meshmatic](https://meshmatic3d.com/), or running a Blender instance and attempting to do it via python, but I couldn't find a solution. Perhaps there's a native/easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this in Blender through Docker via this image https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-blender.

The project structure is

**app.js**

Receives a request via `express`, body contains `https://some-storage.com/model.gltf` and starts a Blender process via `` child_process.exec(`blender -b --addons magic_uv -P /app/src/main.py --log-level -1 -- ${pathToDownloadedGLTFFile}`) ``

**main.py**

```
...

    argv = sys.argv
    argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:]  # get all args after "--"

    param_input_file = argv[0]

    bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath=param_input_file)
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            obj.select_set(True) # select the object
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj # needed to enable Edit mode below
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

    bpy.ops.uv.muv_uvw_box_map(size=instructions['size'], rotation=(instructions['rotationX'], instructions['rotationY'], instructions['rotationZ']))

...

# export back to GLTF and write to /some/dir/model.gltf
```

Regarding the problem with [different directions of UV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx6Zv.jpg), setting `rotation.x` to 270 seems to fix it.