# Compute UV coordinates for threecsg mesh

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js, 3d, threecsg

for a university project I created a threecsg subtract in ThreeJS. I want to apply a texture for this mesh. But the missing uv coordinates after the processing is causing me some trouble. This needs to be a threecsg, because this a project requirement.

This is how the mesh looks like now: [screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ0av.jpg)

I found some code here: [THREE.js generate UV coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774648/three-js-generate-uv-coordinate)

And it did get me closer to the solution. The side faces are now facing the applied texture in the right way: [screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Xidq.jpg)

The upside has many weird faces. I tried to use the THREE.SimplifyModifier to get fewer faces so I might be able to calculate and set the uv-coordinates by myself, but I failed.

I thought it might be a solution to "just iterate" over the up- and downside and to kinda "cut of" the texture at the border, like it would be if the mesh were a cube. The mesh has about 350 Faces, I probably could be able to set the corner vertices but it would be nice if the uv-coordinates of the vertices in between could be calculated - but I have no idea how to to this. I do not mind about the side where cylinder is cut off, because you will not see it at the end.

thank you so much!

Comment: Please include code demonstrating what you've tried to reproduce a minimal example of your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The CSG library I'm maintaining preserves UV coordinates from cut geometry.

https://github.com/manthrax/THREE-CSGMesh

http://vectorslave.com/csg/CSGDemo.html

http://vectorslave.com/csg/CSGShinyDemo.html

@JonasOe